# Remote Desktop Connection Randomly cannot connect

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, windows-server-2008-r2

I manage a number of remote servers through sonicwall VPN connections, I have been having issues when switching between sites. So for example I log off the remote desktop session on server A, swap over the VPN connection and try to connect to server B it doesn't work.

I have been able to log onto them all before, and sometimes continuously trying gets me in. Does anyone know what could cause this? It would be great to find a fix so I can log in first time every time!

chris

Comment: Try googling 'sonicwall terminal services vpn mtu'.   A friend of mine ran into this the other day and it was due to the MTU sizes not matching up on the WAN side of the connection on a sonicwall firewall.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this happen. Sometimes when I remote into a server and I kill the connection without a graceful log off, the TS manager holds the connection as active. So when I try to login to any other server or the same one at a later time, the TS manager fails to connect me due to an idle connection that is in a hung state. Usually Terminal Service manager allows for two connections by default - an remote console connection and one other (I forget the name of it). I would suggest verifying the TS manager that is responsible for building the connections to make sure that there aren't any active/idle connections hanging.